# How to find limits involving trigonometric functions as $x\to 0$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry

Problem: find the limit

1. $lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{\tan(3x)}{\sin(2x)}$
2. $lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\dfrac{(\sin(2x) + 3)}{(\cos(7x)-8)}$

#### Note

I am able to solve the first one using l'Hopitals, but I really want to be able to solve problems like this without it. Any tips/solutions much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know the limits $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\tan x}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.

So, let's manipulate the first limit as follows:

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\tan 3x}{\sin 2x} = \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{\frac{\tan 3x}{x}}{\frac{\sin 2x}{x}} = \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{3}{2}\dfrac{\frac{\tan 3x}{3x}}{\frac{\sin 2x}{2x}}$.

Do you see how to proceed from here?

For the second one, both the numerator and denominator are continuous for all $x$ and the denominator isn't zero. What does this tell you about the limit?

Comment: I just divided the numerator and denominator by $x$.

Comment: Dividing the numerator and denominator by $x$ is the same as dividing the fraction by $\frac{x}{x} = 1$. Also, $\frac{\tan x}{x} \neq 1$ for most values of $x$. However, you can say that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan x}{x} = 1$. Also, $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan ax}{ax} = 1$ for any $a \neq 0$.